# Why my k8s deployment on Azure AKS was scaled on single node pools only?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, node-pools

I have a `hello-world` app that was deployed on AKS with HPA enabled.

I have 2 these node pools:

[image]

I haven't set any node assignment configuration yet:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

FYI:

- `spotnode` pools have autoscaling from 0-2 nodes
- `agentpool` pools have manual scaling with fixed 1 node.

Current behavior:

- When HPA performed, pods are created and got running on `agentpool` only

My expectation is:

- I want my pods will be created on `spotnodes` + other node pools, except the `agentpool`

Question 1: How can I achieve this expectation, I know 1 possible way is to follow the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)?

Question 2: Why my k8s deployment on Azure AKS was scaled on single node pools (`agentpool`) only?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: How can I make pods created on spotnodes + other node pools, except the agentpool?

- Use node affinity

Question 2: Why my k8s deployment on Azure AKS was scaled on single node pools (agentpool) only?

- Because `spotnodes` pool have no active nodes, and because of the reason below.
- Do not use GUI to configure nodepool scaling, it will not work (at this time), you need to use Azure CLI to configure autoscaling for your nodepool.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either, however, one may decide to downvote or upvote for any reason they want, so please don't complain about them as we cannot keep track of how many downvotes or upvotes *for what reason*. The only invalid votes are targetted votes, in which a user goes on a spree of upvoting/downvoting one person's posts specifically or just any post they see generally, these are tracked and will be taken action on. I'll remove the additional comment regarding this from your answer though.

Comment: However, one reason I think may be possible for the downvote is two questions in this post. There should only be one, focused question per post. However, to me, it seems like they are two parts of one specific question. It does look focused to me.